# Library not loaded : @rpath/libgfortran.4.dylib

Tags: macos, julia, gfortran, dyld

I wrote a Julia code with [`Games.jl`](https://github.com/QuantEcon/Games.jl),

```
pd_payoff = [9.0 1.0; 10.0 3.0]
A, B = Player(pd_payoff), Player(pd_payoff)
pd = NormalFormGame((A, B))
rpd = RepeatedGame(pd, 0.75)
hp_pts = outerapproximation(rpd; nH=64, maxiter=500, tol=1e-8, verbose=true, nskipprint=10)
```

Then, I have a following error.

```
error compiling #outerapproximation#62: error compiling Optimizer#1: could not load library "/Users/myname/.julia/packages/Clp/4DejL/deps/usr/lib/libClp.1.13.11.dylib"

dlopen(/Users/myname/.julia/packages/Clp/4DejL/deps/usr/lib/libClp.1.13.11.dylib, 1): Library not loaded: @rpath/libgfortran.4.dylib   
   Referenced from: /Users/myname/.julia/packages/Clp/4DejL/deps/usr/lib/libClp.1.13.11.dylib 
   Reason: image not found
```

My `/Users/myname/.julia/packages/Clp/4DejL/deps/usr/lib/` directory is like this:

```
MyMacBook-Pro-2:~ myname$ ls ~/.julia/packages/Clp/4DejL/deps/usr/lib/
   libClp.1.13.11.dylib     libClpSolver.1.13.11.dylib  libCoinUtils.la         libOsiClp.dylib         libcoinlapack.la
   libClp.1.dylib           libClpSolver.1.dylib        libOsi.la               libOsiClp.la            libcoinmetis.la
   libClp.dylib             libClpSolver.dylib          libOsiClp.1.13.11.dylib libOsiCommonTests.la    libcoinmumps.la
   libClp.la                libClpSolver.la             libOsiClp.1.dylib       libcoinblas.la          pkgconfig
```

Does anyone have an idea to resolve this `Library not found` error? I'm not familiar with library system.
I think there is something wrong in my local environment.

Comment: It looks like there are issues with your `gfortran` installation: a. you don't have it at all, b. you have it in wrong place. Note that you can always alter `rpath` of the library using `install_name_tool` - take a look here (at the bottom of the article: http://www.owsiak.org/setting-up-googletest-on-macos/). Also, make sure you have `gfortran` installed (you can do it via `brew` from the package or from the sources: http://www.owsiak.org/building-opencoarrays-on-macos-everything-from-the-sources-gcc-9-2-0/)

Comment: I think this is a bug in clp, there is nothing you can do on your machine. I might have a fix for it, could you please open an issue in https://github.com/JuliaOpt/Clp.jl/issues/new and tag me (`@giordano`)?

Comment: Yet another alternative is to use `Docker` based installation of the `Fortran`. This way, you can isolate whole environment inside container and use it as it was Linux: https://github.com/mkowsiak/coarrays-docker

Comment: I try the code on my machine, everything wase fine. Ubuntu 18.04.3, julia 1.3.1, Game commit d5cce6e7-4428-536b-a17f-94dfa0e3a07a

Answer (score 0):

It really depends whether you want to play with `Julia` natively or whether you are in a rush and ready to use `Docker` based installation.

If you can sacrifice native approach, you can create simple `Docker` based container (by building in on the following `Dockerfile`):

```
FROM ubuntu:18.10

LABEL description="Environment for running Julia based codes"

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y git
RUN apt-get install -y vim
RUN apt-get install -y libopenmpi-dev
RUN apt-get install -y openmpi-bin
RUN apt-get install -y gfortran
RUN apt-get install -y open-coarrays-bin
RUN apt-get install -y make
RUN apt-get install -y tree
RUN apt-get install -y gdb
RUN apt-get install -y curl

RUN mkdir -p /opt
ADD run.sh /opt/run.sh
RUN chmod +x /opt/run.sh

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash fortcoder

USER fortcoder
WORKDIR /home/fortcoder

RUN echo 'PS1="[\u@coarray-docker:\w ] $ "' >> /home/fortcoder/.bashrc
RUN echo 'PATH=/home/fortcoder/opt/julia/julia-1.3.1/bin:${PATH}' >> /home/fortcoder/.bashrc

RUN mkdir -p /home/fortcoder/code

RUN mkdir -p /home/fortcoder/opt/julia
RUN curl -o /home/fortcoder/opt/julia/julia-1.3.1-linux-x86_64.tar.gz https://julialang-s3.julialang.org/bin/linux/x64/1.3/julia-1.3.1-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
RUN tar zxf /home/fortcoder/opt/julia/julia-1.3.1-linux-x86_64.tar.gz -C /home/fortcoder/opt/julia/

CMD /opt/run.sh
```

make sure to put `run.sh` next to `Dockerfile`

```
#!/bin/bash

cat << EOF


      ***************************************************
                      Juli Docker for macOS
        -----------------------------------------------
           This Docker image allows you to play with
           Julia on macOS.

           Remember that you can easily attach other
           samples by passing

           -v ~/dir_with_code:/home/fortcoder/code

           to your 'docker -it' command

        -----------------------------------------------


EOF

/bin/bash
```

Then, you can create the container following way:

```
> docker build -t coarrays .
> mkdir sample_code
> docker run -i -t -v `pwd`/sample_code:/home/fortcoder/code coarrays
```

You can map your macOS based directory (`sample_code`) to a directory inside container.

Once you are in the container, simply run `julia`

```
> julia
> using Pkg
> Pkg.clone("https://github.com/QuantEcon/Games.jl")
┌ Warning: Pkg.clone is only kept for legacy CI script reasons, please use `add`
└ @ Pkg.API /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.3/Pkg/src/API.jl:664
   Cloning git-repo `https://github.com/QuantEcon/Games.jl`
...
...
  Building CMake ─────→ `~/.julia/packages/CMake/nSK2r/deps/build.log`
  Building MbedTLS ───→ `~/.julia/packages/MbedTLS/a1JFn/deps/build.log`
  Building NLopt ─────→ `~/.julia/packages/NLopt/eqN9a/deps/build.log`
  Building CodecBzip2 → `~/.julia/packages/CodecBzip2/T5yr7/deps/build.log`
  Building CodecZlib ─→ `~/.julia/packages/CodecZlib/5t9zO/deps/build.log`
  Building FFTW ──────→ `~/.julia/packages/FFTW/qqcBj/deps/build.log`
  Building Rmath ─────→ `~/.julia/packages/Rmath/BoBag/deps/build.log`
  Building Clp ───────→ `~/.julia/packages/Clp/4DejL/deps/build.log`
julia>
```

once `Games` is installed, you can quit `julia` and run your code. Simply create file inside `Docker` container (`code.jl`).

```
using Games
pd_payoff = [9.0 1.0; 10.0 3.0]
A, B = Player(pd_payoff), Player(pd_payoff)
pd = NormalFormGame((A, B))
rpd = RepeatedGame(pd, 0.75)
hp_pts = outerapproximation(rpd; nH=64, maxiter=500, tol=1e-8, verbose=true, nskipprint=10)
```

and run it

```
> julia ./code.jl
10  0.08865814883358247 (2.709875698216042, 2.7098756982160457)
20  0.004992651968453998    (2.9836620808639114, 2.983662080863915)
30  0.0002811537800653241   (2.9990799543504063, 2.9990799543504094)
40  1.5832757529921082e-5   (2.9999481889957704, 2.9999481889957793)
50  8.915982272483802e-7    (2.999997082340249, 2.999997082340251)
60  5.020902937857841e-8    (2.999999835696323, 2.9999998356963244)
>
```